# Admob Unable to set adSize property on xCode 8

Tags: swift, admob

I have followed all steps on: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start

but i'm getting a error:

```
Google Unable to set adSize property. Not enough space to show ad with custom size, {1000, 1000}.
```

the bannerView has a auto layout with 320 width and 50 height.

Looks like Admob is ignoring the constraints.

i have also tried to add:

```
BannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeBanner
```

and

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

But both didn't work.

Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: share code you have written.

Comment: Sounds like your auto layout isn't correct.

Comment: I have the same problem with Objc-c. But the strupid thing is - ALL TEST ADS where display correctly, only live ads get this error.